# UnsupportedClassVersionError: f/xx : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, selenium

Can any one help me out iam getting below error message if iam going to run my selenium java program.
I have installed new selenium-java-3.0 version files in library. 
Not able to run my program can any one help?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: f/xx : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Comment: You need java 8...

Comment: `Unsupported major.minor version` hints at an older Java version being used to run an application than it was compiled with (at least one of the classes), `52.0` means at least Java 8 is required to load and use the class (i.e. run the application).